# How can I build a search and replace Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataset

I have a dataset that looks like this

```
import pandas as pd
dts1 = pd.DataFrame([[0.5,0.7,0.1,0.9,0.1],
                [0.7,0.9,0.11,0.02,0.1]])
dts1.head()
```

For each row in the data set I want to replace the max value to 1 and if it's not the maximum then replace it with 0

So each row should look like

```
0,1,0,0,0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compare to the max per row and convert the boolean to integer:

```
dts1.eq(dts1.max(axis=1), axis=0).astype(int)
```

Output:

```
   0  1  2  3  4
0  0  0  0  1  0
1  0  1  0  0  0
```